# How to turn this MySQL SELECT query into a DELETE query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-delete

I want to delete certain items from the database. I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sheets, entries 
WHERE entries.sheetID = sheets.id AND sheets.clientID = 13
```

This works, and returns 2 results.

Now I want to turn this `SELECT` query into a `DELETE` query. However, the following doesn't work:

```
DELETE FROM sheets, entries 
WHERE entries.sheetID = sheets.id AND sheets.clientID = 13
```

MySQL throws the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE entries.sheetID =
>   sheets.id AND sheets.clientID = 13' at
>   line 1

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to delete rows from sheets, from entries, or from both?

Comment: Andomar: I want to delete all sheets and sheet entries from client 13. I'd rather not use more than 1 query if it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MySQL 4 and up supports [deleting from multiple tables at once](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html), using the following syntax:

```
DELETE sheets, entries
FROM sheets, entries 
WHERE entries.sheetID = sheets.id AND sheets.clientID = 13
```

If you're using MySQL below version 4, then you need to delete rows from one table at a time, and you can use one of the other solutions posted here.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
DELETE sheets, entries 
FROM sheets, entries
WHERE entries.sheetID = sheets.id AND sheets.clientID = 13
```

I googled SQL delete from 2 tables at once and found [this forum post](http://www.webmaster-talk.com/php-forum/29782-mysql-delete-from-2-tables-once.html#post149048)

Comment: Another correct, yet slightly less documented answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

MySQL will let you delete over a join, but you must specify which columns, so using your example, the correct syntax would be

```
DELETE sheets.*, entries.* FROM sheets, entries WHERE entries.sheetID = sheets.id AND sheets.clientID = 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this

```
DELETE FROM sheets
FROM sheets, entries 
WHERE entries.sheetID = sheets.id AND sheets.clientID = 13
```

if you want to delete from sheets and

```
DELETE FROM entries
FROM sheets, entries 
WHERE entries.sheetID = sheets.id AND sheets.clientID = 13
```

if its from entries

Comment: The problem is I want to delete from both at the same time. I want to delete all sheets and sheet entries from client 13. I'd rather not use more than 1 query if it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only `DELETE` from one table at a time.

```
DELETE FROM entries
WHERE entries.sheetID IN
(SELECT ID FROM sheets WHERE clientID = 13)

DELETE FROM sheets
WHERE sheets.clientID = 13
```

Comment: MySQL actually allows a multi-table delete http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete from one table at a time.  If you want to drive both deletes from the same query, you can do something like the following:

```
DELETE from sheets where id in (
SELECT sheets.id
FROM sheets, entries 
WHERE entries.sheetID = sheets.id AND sheets.clientID = 13);
DELETE from entries where id in (
SELECT entries.id
FROM sheets, entries 
WHERE entries.sheetID = sheets.id AND sheets.clientID = 13);
```

Comment: The second one would fail since you have already deleted the joining table's rows

Comment: This is apparently not true in MySQL which, as stated in other answers, supports the DELETE statement the OP is trying to create (with slightly different syntax).